# MS Project: Show annual project cost

Tags: ms-project, cost-management

I am currently planning a project in MS Project. After allocating all resources and other cost to the tasks I need to present the annual budget of the project (split into manpower and direct cost).

How can I show the project cost per resource per (fiscal) year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Display the Resource Usage view.
- Add costs to the right side (Right click in the timescaled portion
  and select Cost from the shortcutmenu).
- Zoom the view out to yearly.